# How to get different auto_increment value depending on value of different key

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a table set up for todo items, the main columns are `hash` and `owner`. I would like to have it set up in a way where `hash` auto increments based on the value of `owner` and if a value was deleted all the `hash` values would automatically update with new incremented values.

Say there were 3 users, for simplicity I'll set their IDs in `owner` as 1, 2 and 3. Each one has 3 items, the table would look like this

```
hash owner
1        1
2        1
3        1
1        2
2        2
3        2
1        3
2        3
3        3
```

If I was to add a new entry for owner 1 it would auto increment the hash to 4 creating a table like this

```
hash owner
1        1
2        1
3        1
4        1
1        2
2        2
3        2
1        3
2        3
3        3
```

Then, if I ran `DELETE FROM todo WHERE hash = 2 AND owner = 1` the hashes for entries linked to owner 1 would change to `1 | 2 | 3` rather than being `1 | 3 | 4`

If I then added a new user with `INSERT INTO todo SET owner = 4` they would get their own "set of hashes".

Is this at all possible or am I asking for too much?

The only reason I would like do this is so each user can have their own easy to remember hashes rather than something like `jIUxdi3XjaDv`

Comment: unless you provide the hash, innodb auto increment does not do this.

Comment: however, myisam can do this.

Comment: @PeterHe do you know of any guides that would aid me in recreating this within myisam?

Comment: You define the hash as int not null auto_increment, owner int not null, and other columns. Then define a PK on both owner and hash columns. Please keep in mind, myisam does not support transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ordinary auto increment column in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
             (ordinal integer
                      NOT NULL
                      AUTO_INCREMENT,
              owner integer,
              UNIQUE (ordinal));
```

If you want you can make it the primary key of the table too instead of just declaring it unique.

Then use a view that calculates the hash by counting the occurrences of that auto increment column, that are less than or equal to the current one.

```
CREATE VIEW weiv
AS
SELECT (SELECT count(*)
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.owner = t1.owner
                     AND t2.ordinal <= t1.ordinal) hash,
       t1.owner
       FROM elbat t1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=55c8adeb25e15d0e342036f2f92fdd28)

In versions of MySQL that support `row_number()` (version 8.0 and above) instead of the subquery `row_number()` can be used in the view.

```
CREATE VIEW weiv
AS
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.owner
                          ORDER BY t1.ordinal) hash,
       t1.owner
       FROM elbat t1;
```